# Send Json data in the push notification (MarketingCloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, android

Is it possible send json data in the push notification? Exist any sample how to work plus using MarketingCloud steps to fire push?

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom parameters to a push notification using **Custom Keys** functionnality

- Allow custom keys in Mobile Push https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_custom_keys.htm&type=5
- Retrieve Custom keys in App using SDK http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/custom-keys.html

Json Data would be inserted in the custom key value manually or retrieved from a Data Extension using AMPScript.